# Волнующий или волнительный?

Tags: употребление-слов

Опыт - волнующий или всё-таки волнительный?

В чем смысловая разница этих слов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ

ВОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ, Разг. (обычно в речи актёров).Волнующий, приводящий в состояние радостного ожидания чего-л. (обычно в речи актеров).

ИЗ СОВРЕМЕННОЙ ПОЭЗИИ:

"Ловить стихов волнующие звуки, Как и любить, не каждому дано. Кому–то слаще буйное вино, А не души полуночные муки" (Г. Шеховцов). "Мне не сдержать волнительные чувства, И не скрывая, своего греха, Я , как поэт беременный искусством, С надеждой жду рождения стиха (Б. Межиборский).

Сосуществование этих двух слов имеет длительную историю.Интересный материал дан на сайте http://kuzdra-glokaya.livejournal.com/8212.html

ВЫДЕРЖКИ ИЗ ЭТОЙ СТАТЬИ

"Волнительный" в русских словарях появилось в 1704 году, а "волнительно" - в самом конце прошлого (XIX) века, сначала в артистической среде, а в нормативных словарях оно было зафиксировано лишь в 80-е гг. ХХ века, да и то с пометой "разговорное". Однако в русской речи известно уже столетием раньше: употребляли его и Лев Толстой, и Чехов, и Чуковский. Вариант "волнующе", "волнующий" является книжным, это слова высокого стиля, по происхождению церковнославянские, которые в разговорной речи стали заменяться русскими по образованию словами "волнительно", "волнительный".

"В последнее время часто встречаю слово волнительный, и оно неприятно режет слух. И ведь нельзя сказать, что оно является нарушением языковой нормы, просто не лежит к нему душа, и всё тут. Поискала о нём информацию -картина получается неоднородной. Нередко можно встретить недоумение, а порой и негодование по поводу этого слова. Правда, эксперты, которым адресовался вопрос, негодование не разделили, хоть и ушли от прямого ответа.

Никак не пойму, почему стали говорить «волнительно» вместо «волнующе». Но поскольку высший свет ввел в обиход такое жеманство, приходится и мне, оттопыривая мизинец, случаи эксклюзивных переживаний называть «волнительными». Вот-вот, есть, по-моему, какое-то жеманство, нарочитость в этом слове, и не убеждают никакие доводы в пользу этого слова. Мой вердикт -отказать!

ВЫВОД

Итак, ВОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ - способный волновать, ВОЛНУЮЩИЙ - тот, который волнует. Если речь идет о названии "Волнующий опыт" (сборник РЕАЛЬНЫХ эротических рассказов), то оно здесь вполне уместно. "Волнительный опыт" - это, скорее, были бы идеальные фантазии на ту же тему.

И еще несколько слов о различии слов.  Это могут быть разные оттенки смысла, как в нашем случае. Если же смысл одинаковый, то можно считать, что ВОЛНУЮЩИЙ - это нейтральный стиль, а ВОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ - поэтический, но только  не разговорный.